# I am unable to Stamp Content on a PDF using Itext

Tags: java, itext

The functionality of Code is quite simple and requires you to stamp content over an existing PDF using Itext. The Input is an `InputStream`, and returns a `ByteArrayOutputStream` for Servlet response.

Somehow it is returning the entire PDF without stamping any content and returns no error/exception. The code **once worked** when this function was part of the servlet, but it did **not** work since it was shifted to a new class (and Watermark attributes are now initialized in the constructor).

```
    public ByteArrayOutputStream watermarkPDFDocument (InputStream WatermarkedFileInputStream) throws DocumentException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytearrayos =new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try
    {   
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(WatermarkedFileInputStream);
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, bytearrayos);
        PdfContentByte PdfContentOver; //PDFContent to get page data and to splash over pages. 
        Rectangle pagesize;
        float WatermarkCenterX, WatermarkCenterY;

        // loop over every page
        int TotalNoOfPages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        for (int i = 1; i <= TotalNoOfPages; i++) {
            // get page size and position
            pagesize = reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(i);
            WatermarkCenterX = (pagesize.getLeft() + pagesize.getRight()) / 2;
            WatermarkCenterY = (pagesize.getTop() + pagesize.getBottom()) / 2;
            LOG.debug("Center of page  - [" + WatermarkCenterX + " , " + WatermarkCenterY+"]");

            //Initializing PageNo Phrase for Footer
            FooterPageNoPhrase = new Phrase("Page " + String.valueOf(i) + " of " + String.valueOf(TotalNoOfPages),FooterFont);

            PdfContentOver = stamper.getOverContent(i);
            PdfContentOver.saveState();

            //Setting Watermark opacity
            PdfGState CenterState = new PdfGState();
            PdfGState FooterState = new PdfGState();
            CenterState.setFillOpacity(CenterFontOpacity);
            FooterState.setFillOpacity(FooterFontOpacity);

            PdfContentOver.setGState(CenterState);//Sets Transparency for Center
            //Watermark at center
            ColumnText.showTextAligned(PdfContentOver, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, CenterPhraseDocState, WatermarkCenterX-(CenterFontSize/2), WatermarkCenterY+(CenterFontSize/2), 45);
            ColumnText.showTextAligned(PdfContentOver, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, CenterPhraseDocLogic, WatermarkCenterX+(CenterFontSize/2), WatermarkCenterY-(CenterFontSize/2), 45);
            LOG.debug("Stamped Center Watermark - " + CenterPhraseDocState + " , " + CenterPhraseDocLogic);
            PdfContentOver.setGState(FooterState); //Sets Transparency for Footer
            //Watermark at Footer Row 1
            ColumnText.showTextAligned(PdfContentOver, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, FooterPhraseDocState, (pagesize.getLeft()+ FooterDistanceFromLeft), (pagesize.getBottom() + FooterRow1Height), 0);
            ColumnText.showTextAligned(PdfContentOver, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, FooterPhraseDocNumber, (pagesize.getRight()- FooterDistanceFromRight), (pagesize.getBottom() + FooterRow1Height), 0);
            ColumnText.showTextAligned(PdfContentOver, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, FooterPhraseDocName, WatermarkCenterX, (pagesize.getBottom() + FooterRow1Height), 0);
            //Watermark at Footer Row 2
            ColumnText.showTextAligned(PdfContentOver, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, FooterPhraseConfidential, WatermarkCenterX, (pagesize.getBottom() + FooterRow2Height), 0);
            ColumnText.showTextAligned(PdfContentOver, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, FooterPageNoPhrase, (pagesize.getRight()- FooterDistanceFromRight), (pagesize.getBottom() + FooterRow2Height), 0);
            LOG.debug("Stamped Footer Watermark - " + FooterPhraseDocState + " , " + FooterPhraseDocNumber + " , " + FooterPhraseDocName + " , " + FooterPhraseConfidential);
            PdfContentOver.restoreState();
        }

        stamper.close();
        reader.close();

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        LOG.error("ERROR while retrieving primary content's file  ", e);
    }
    return bytearrayos;


}
```

Here is the logger when I try to run the code - [Logger Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yn92E.jpg)
Since no `Exceptions` are caught and Servlet Response returns the PDF generated from `InputStream`, and the `Itext Phrases` returns a non-empty value. I suspect the error lies around  `PDFStates` or writing the phrases onto text but after staring at it for hours, I am unable to figure out where things are going wrong.

Edit - I won't be able to attach the log file since it contains details from other part of the system. I am writing all the log debugs/errors from the code.

```
2018-06-14 05:28:45,909 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(150)-132.189.104.47] wt.log4j.jmx.LoggerRepositoryMonitor.levelChanged - Logger=com.bsci.plm.watermark.BSCWatermarkFileGeneration, NewLevel=ALL
796: 2018-06-14 05:28:56,702 DEBUG [ajp-bio-8011-exec-2] com.bsci.plm.watermark.BSCWatermarkFileGeneration wcadmin - Font Size for Center Watermark - 30
797: 2018-06-14 05:28:56,702 DEBUG [ajp-bio-8011-exec-2] com.bsci.plm.watermark.BSCWatermarkFileGeneration wcadmin - Font Size for Footer Watermark - 10
798: 2018-06-14 05:28:56,702 DEBUG [ajp-bio-8011-exec-2] com.bsci.plm.watermark.BSCWatermarkFileGeneration wcadmin - RGB for Center Watermark - [255, 0, 0]
799: 2018-06-14 05:28:56,702 DEBUG [ajp-bio-8011-exec-2] com.bsci.plm.watermark.BSCWatermarkFileGeneration wcadmin - RGB for Footer Watermark - [0, 0, 0]
800: 2018-06-14 05:28:56,702 DEBUG [ajp-bio-8011-exec-2] com.bsci.plm.watermark.BSCWatermarkFileGeneration wcadmin - Opacity for Center Watermark - 0.4
801: 2018-06-14 05:28:56,702 DEBUG [ajp-bio-8011-exec-2] com.bsci.plm.watermark.BSCWatermarkFileGeneration wcadmin - Opacity for Footer Watermark - 0.9
802: 2018-06-14 05:28:56,702 DEBUG [ajp-bio-8011-exec-2] com.bsci.plm.watermark.BSCWatermarkFileGeneration wcadmin - Confidential Watermark - Confidential. Unauthorized use is prohibited.
803: 2018-06-14 05:28:56,702 DEBUG [ajp-bio-8011-exec-2] com.bsci.plm.watermark.BSCWatermarkFileGeneration wcadmin - Watermark BusinessLogic - 
804: 2018-06-14 05:28:56,730 DEBUG [ajp-bio-8011-exec-2] com.bsci.plm.watermark.BSCWatermarkFileGeneration wcadmin - Center of page - [306.0 , 396.0]
805: 2018-06-14 05:28:56,730 DEBUG [ajp-bio-8011-exec-2] com.bsci.plm.watermark.BSCWatermarkFileGeneration wcadmin - Stamped Center Watermark - [Released (Expiring)] , []
806: 2018-06-14 05:28:56,730 DEBUG [ajp-bio-8011-exec-2] com.bsci.plm.watermark.BSCWatermarkFileGeneration wcadmin - Stamped Footer Watermark - [Released (Expiring)] , [92001458 B.3] , [Global TMP 2] , [Confidential. Unauthorized use is prohibited.]
807: 2018-06-14 05:28:56,731 DEBUG [ajp-bio-8011-exec-2] com.bsci.plm.watermark.BSCWatermarkFileGeneration wcadmin - Center of page - [306.0 , 396.0]
808: 2018-06-14 05:28:56,731 DEBUG [ajp-bio-8011-exec-2] com.bsci.plm.watermark.BSCWatermarkFileGeneration wcadmin - Stamped Center Watermark - [Released (Expiring)] , []
809: 2018-06-14 05:28:56,731 DEBUG [ajp-bio-8011-exec-2] com.bsci.plm.watermark.BSCWatermarkFileGeneration wcadmin - Stamped Footer Watermark - [Released (Expiring)] , [92001458 B.3] , [Global TMP 2] , [Confidential. Unauthorized use is prohibited.]
810: 2018-06-14 05:28:56,731 DEBUG [ajp-bio-8011-exec-2] com.bsci.plm.watermark.BSCWatermarkFileGeneration wcadmin - Center of page - [306.0 , 396.0]
811: 2018-06-14 05:28:56,732 DEBUG [ajp-bio-8011-exec-2] com.bsci.plm.watermark.BSCWatermarkFileGeneration wcadmin - Stamped Center Watermark - [Released (Expiring)] , []
812: 2018-06-14 05:28:56,732 DEBUG [ajp-bio-8011-exec-2] com.bsci.plm.watermark.BSCWatermarkFileGeneration wcadmin - Stamped Footer Watermark - [Released (Expiring)] , [92001458 B.3] , [Global TMP 2] , [Confidential. Unauthorized use is prohibited.]
```

EDIT2 - Adding how the method is called in servlet. The 'IdentifierInfoDocument' and 'SourceFileInputStream' are working correctly since Logger ends up with the right messages for Watermarking and I won't get a response PDF if my InputStream was not generated. The PDF get generated in Response from InputStream and since all Loggers are called, I still think the issues like when phrases are suppose to be stamped on the PDF.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytearrayos = null; //
    try {
        BSCWatermarkFileGeneration WatermarkedFile =new BSCWatermarkFileGeneration(IdentifierInfoDocument(IdentifierInfo));
        bytearrayos = WatermarkedFile.watermarkPDFDocument(SourceFileInputStream(SourceFileServlet));
    } 
    catch (DocumentException e) {
        LOG.error("PDF Document not found - ", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (WTException e) {
        LOG.error("Error while retrieving WTDOC - ", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    catch (NullPointerException e) {
        LOG.error("Error while accessing watermark properties from property file - ", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error("Error while accessing the source Servlet ",e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        LOG.error("Error while accessing integer/float values from property file - ", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ServletOutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
    if(bytearrayos!=null)
        bytearrayos.writeTo(os);
    os.flush();
```

FINAL EDIT - I figured out what went wrong and its really dumb. The opacity were initialized as a local variable instead of the ones I defined in the class. Since I was using them in Logger, I never got any warning about unused variables and couldn't trace the cause.

Comment: please upload the log directly instead of `screenshot` to make it easier to read, thank you

Comment: @Hearen

I have added the lines from the image in text, I won't be able to attach the log file. Sorry about that.

Comment: @AnonyMous At first glance your code looks ok. Probably not this method `watermarkPDFDocument` is broken but instead the way you call it or use its output. Thus, please supply the code of its use. Furthermore, please supply an example incoming PDF and an example outgoing PDF for analysis.

Comment: @mkl

Added the code for method call. Since the PDF's are being generated from 'SourceInputStream' and I am able to get a PDF file in Servlet Response, I believe the issue might be in 'watermarkPDFDocument'. 

There is no Exception and Loggers show that each page is being read and the constructor initialization are correct since the values accessed from 'watermarkPDFDocument' are what I intended them to be.

Comment: I just tested your routine. For some variables I had to guess values, for others I could take them from your log outputs. [The result: A watermarked PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnfXk.png). (A bit ugly due to the guessed values, I think, but watermarked nonetheless. Thus, either your input files are in some way special (XFA forms? Broken?) or the `os` is acting weird (The original PDF written to it before? Not the returned stream at all?), or the missing values (which I guessed to produce a someway working output) in your case cause the watermarks to be invisible.

Comment: *"The opacity were initialized as a local variable instead of the ones I defined in the class."* - that is weird, your method `watermarkPDFDocument` above does not contain such local variables.

Comment: @mkl I was initializing the variables for Opacity/Color/FontSize in a constructor using a Property File and defining them at the start of the class. Every other variable was initialized correctly but for FontOpacity I wrote the code like this
    

"Font CenterFontOpacity = Float.parseFloat(WatermarkProperties.getProperty("CenterFontOpacity"));"


Since there was no Null Exception thrown and no warning displayed due to the local variable being used in Logger, it took me some time to figure out what I did wrong.

Comment: Ah, ok. Well, great you figured it out!